# Excel - User defined function getting is being called even when not active

Tags: vba, excel

I have a user defined function in excel. The function contains Application.Volatile at the top and it works great.

The problem I am experiencing now is that when I have the workbook open (lets call it workbook 1) together with another workbook (call it workbook 2), every time I make a change to workbook 2, all cells in workbook 1 that call this UDF gets a #VALUE! error.
Why is this happening?

I hope I provided enough info. If not please let me know.
Thanks
David

Hi guys, thanks for the help.
Sorry about that... here is the code:

```
Function getTotalReceived(valCell As Range) As Variant
    Application.Volatile

    If ActiveWorkbook.Name <> "SALES.xlsm" Then Return
    Dim receivedWs As Worksheet, reportWs As Worksheet
    Dim items As Range
    Set reportWs = Worksheets("Report")
    Set receivedWs = Worksheets("Received")

    Dim myItem As String, index As Long
    myItem = valCell.Value
    Set items = receivedWs.Range("A:A")
    index = Application.Match(myItem, items, 0)
    If IsError(index) Then
        Debug.Print ("Error: " & myItem)
        Debug.Print (Err.Description)
        GoTo QuitIt
    End If
    Dim lCol As Long, Qty As Double, mySumRange As Range
    Set mySumRange = receivedWs.Range(index & ":" & index)
    Qty = WorksheetFunction.Sum(mySumRange)
QuitIt:
    getTotalReceived = Qty
End Function
```

Comment: You will need to show your UDF code.  If your UDF fails when the containing workbook isn't the ActiveWorkbook then that possibly points to a coding issue in how your UDF addresses ranges.

Comment: **Help us to help you.**    Post your code.

Comment: In a UDF you cannot use normal addressing.  You need to use the `Application.Caller` object for all Excel references.

Comment: @Mr.Mascaro - that's not true.

Comment: @TimWilliams, in a UDF it's absolutely true for all objects that are not passed in as arguments.  If you disagree, I'd like to see some proof.

Comment: How about `Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A4")`  That is perfectly valid in a UDF and there's no *requirement* to use `Application.Caller`  I'm not saying you shouldn't, only that it's not required.

Comment: @TimWilliams, and you can do that if you want to write bad code that will not always work. I live in a world where writing robust and maintainable code is the only option.  Obviously we don't all live in that world.

Comment: @Mr.Mascaro - it seems we only disagree on the meaning of "required".

Comment: `Return` is not a thing in VBA, so as posted your code won't even compile

Comment: Is your lookup sheet in the same workbook as your UDF?

Comment: @TimWilliams - no Return? then how do you exit a function? By the way my code did compile and worked perfect...??   Yes, my lookup sheet is in the same workbook

Comment: To exit a function you use `Exit Function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Function getTotalReceived(valCell As Range) As Variant
    Application.Volatile

    Dim index, v, Qty

    v = valCell.Value

    'do you really need this here?
    If ActiveWorkbook.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then Exit Function

    If Len(v) > 0 Then

        index = Application.Match(v, _
              ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report").Range("A:A"), 0)

        If Not IsError(index) Then
            Qty = Application.Sum(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Received").Rows(index))
        Else
            Qty = "no match"
        End If
    Else
        Qty = ""
    End If

    getTotalReceived = Qty
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is with the use of `ActiveWorkbook`,`ActiveWorksheet` or `ActiveCell` or other `Active_____` objects in your UDF.  Notice that `Application.Volitile` is an application-level property.  Anytime you switch sheets, books, cells, charts, etc. the corresponding "active" object changes.

As an example of proper UDF coding practice I put together this short example:

```
Function appCallerTest() As String
    Dim callerWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim callerWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim callerRange As Range

    Application.Volatile True

    Set callerRange = Application.Caller
    Set callerWorksheet = callerRange.Worksheet
    Set callerWorkbook = callerWorksheet.Parent

    appCallerTest = "This formula is in cell: " & callerRange.Address(False, False) & _
                    " in the sheet: " & callerWorksheet.Name & _
                    " in the workbook: " & callerWorkbook.Name
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. I never knew about these "caller" options. However, I still can't get it to work properly. As of now, the cell was calling this function while passing the actual cell A and row number. E.g., `getTotalReceived($A2)`. I changed it to `getTotalReceived("A")` and then I changed the function to `myItem = callerSheet.Range(valCell & callerRange.row).Value`. But I am still getting the same behavior.

Comment: Application.Caller creates buggy behaviour (sometimes complains of a circular reference) if you use it in a function that already has a Range as a parameter.  Resolving the Workbook from the Range is always safer.

Comment: @Comintern, I've been using it for more than a decade and never gotten any buggy behavior.  User error?

Answer (score 1):

You actually have 2 errors in your function.  The first was partially addressed by Mr. Mascaro - you need to use the Range reference that was passed to the function to resolve the Workbook that it is from.  You can do this by drilling down through the Parent properties.

The second issue is that you are testing to see if `Application.Match` returned a valid `index` with the `IsError` function.  This isn't doing what you think it's doing - `IsError` checks to see if *another cell's function* returned an error, not the previous line.  In fact, if `Application.Match` raises an error, it is in your function so you have to handle it. I believe the error you need to trap is a type mismatch (error 13).

This should resolve both issues:

```
Function getTotalReceived(valCell As Range) As Variant
    Application.Volatile

    Dim book As Workbook
    Set book = valCell.Parent.Parent

    If book.Name <> "SALES.xlsm" Then Exit Function

    Dim receivedWs As Worksheet, reportWs As Worksheet
    Dim items As Range
    Set reportWs = book.Worksheets("Report")
    Set receivedWs = book.Worksheets("Received")

    Dim myItem As String, index As Long
    myItem = valCell.Value

    Set items = receivedWs.Range("A:A")

    On Error Resume Next
    index = Application.Match(myItem, items, 0)
    If Err.Number = 13 Then GoTo QuitIt
    On Error GoTo 0

    Dim lCol As Long, Qty As Double, mySumRange As Range
    Set mySumRange = receivedWs.Range(index & ":" & index)
    Qty = WorksheetFunction.Sum(mySumRange)
QuitIt:
    getTotalReceived = Qty
End Function
```

Comment: THANKS! Works perfectly! - - - **Regarding Error #1**, I see what you mean by using parent. It seems that the error was being caused by the lines of the lookup and not in the actual processing of the received cell as the parameter - true? - - -  **Regarding Error #2**, Correct, I was looking for a mismatch and your code handles it great - Thanks! And I understand my mistake - thanks for explaning

Comment: The second error you describe in the poster's code would have been fine if they'd defined `index` as Variant instead of Long. When you don't use `WorksheetFunction` in the call, `Application.Match` will return an error value if it doesn't make a match, which you can test for using `IsError()`, thus avoiding the need for `On Error resume Next` Like the poster you're also using Return, which is not a way to exit a function in VBA.